# How to preview/display an image after uploading at the side of the upload button in Vue.js (Element.ui)?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, file-upload, element-ui

I am working on displaying/previewing an image after uploading it. I am trying to upload an image and then make an axios/AJAX call.

Please find the code below:

HTML code:

```
        <span>User Name</span>
           <input v-model="person_name" placeholder="Edit Me">
           <br>
           
        <!--Uploading pic -->
        <span>Display Pic</span>
           <input type="file" name="file" />
           <br>

        <!-- I want to display this uploaded pic here, before submitting the form -->

        <!-- Skipping the code to submit (button code, etc) the form -->
```

Javascript Code --> AJAX/FETCH call to the API

```
            var formData = new FormData();
            var fileField = document.querySelector("input[type='file']");

            formData.append('username', this.person_name);
            
            formData.append('File', fileField.files[0]); // getting the file attached
            
            const body = formData;

            const init = {
                method: 'POST',
                body
            };

            fetch('http://..xyz....com', init)
                .then((response) => {
                return response.json(); // or .text() or .blob() ...
            })
                .then((text) => {
                // text is the response body
            })
                .catch((e) => {
                // error in e.message
            });
        },
```

How do I display or preview the picture/photo as an avatar or something after uploading the pic.

Comment: Hi @skate_23, after saving the image on the server, you could send back image's path and put it inside an `img` tag :)

Comment: Thanks. Please could you tell me how I can send back the image's path immediately after uploading it? Kinda trying to figure that out from some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you can preview the uploaded image before sending it to the server. You can attach an `@change` event listener on your `input type='file'` to listen to the change event and then access the image uploaded by `event.target.files[0]`. Then change the `src` of the `img` tag with the uploaded image `src`.

[Live Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-2dmqnr?file=src/App.vue)

You can also send it to server immediately after uploading it in the `preview()` method or you can use `upload` button to send it to the server.

**Your Vue Template:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img id="image" :src="imgSrc" />
    <input type=file @change="preview">
  <div>
    <button @click="upload()">Upload</button>
  </div>
  <div> {{ uploaded }} </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Script:**

```
data: () => ({
  imgSrc: '',
  uploaded: ''
}),

methods: {
  preview(e) {
    var pic = document.getElementById('image')
    let imgSrc = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    this.imgSrc = imgSrc
  },
  upload() {
    this.uploaded = this.imgSrc;
  }
}
```